# Rating star is cutting from the end

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution, ratingbar

i have implemented android native rating bar but when i set number of star to 10 it will cut from the end of the screen its happening in some devices can anybody help me how can i manage to display 10 star consistently on all mobile devices?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tValueLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />



<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please provide the full code of your layout. Thanks

Comment: @Muhammad Farhan please check i have updated the question

Comment: why you add layout_marginBottom in parent layout ??

Comment: Check updated answer please @Android

Answer (score 0):

try this to minimize size of stars

```
android:scaleX=".4"
android:scaleY=".4"
```

I hope it will work with you

Comment: Still cutting from end

Answer (score 0):

your RatingBar is cutting from end due to no space in screen to fit 10 star.
Solution for it is to reduce the size of star. there is no direct method by which we can reduce size of star. In your case scaleX and scaleY will works. Pls use below code for RatingBar

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:scaleX=".8"
    android:scaleY=".8"
    android:translationX="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />
```

Comment: Still cutting from end

Comment: then pls try with .6 or .4 scale.

Comment: its working with 5 star but when i set 10 star its cutting

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your width parameter as per your need:

android:layout_width="xx dp"